# Alter event and set ends to null

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey I've created an event that ends at a specific timestamp and wish to alter it to run infinitly.

I've tried running :

```
ALTER EVENT event_name 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '5' MINUTE 
STARTS '2013-10-21 14:49' ENDS NULL 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE    DO [code];
```

But I get the error Error Code: 1543. ENDS is either invalid or before STARTS

How can this be done? I know I can set a date in the far future that would seem like infinity, but I wish to set ENDS to null.

If I simpley exclude the ENDS parameter, it gets stuck with the old ends date, You can see so when you : `select * from information_schema.events`
But the event does continue to run as if ENDS was null. And that is mostly what I need to achieve.

Comment: `ENDS` is useless see : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-event.html

Comment: What do you want with `NULL`? If you need infinite time definition  for your event, just omit `ENDS` clause - and that's it. `NULL` has nothing to do with this and it can't work just because 'you want to use NULL'

Comment: If I run `select * from information_schema.events` I get the old ENDS date, and I am using the information schema throughout my code, though the event does occur

Comment: It looks like there's a design defect in the ALTER syntax for events. your intuition may be telling you that you can remove the ENDS clause by setting it to NULL, but you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `ENDS` parameter is optional, else you can specify a future date. 
`ENDS` must be followed by a timestamp.

> An EVERY clause may contain an optional ENDS clause. **The ENDS keyword is followed by a timestamp value that tells MySQL when the event should stop repeating**. You may also use + INTERVAL interval with ENDS; for instance, EVERY 12 HOUR STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 4 WEEK is equivalent to “every twelve hours, beginning thirty minutes from now, and ending four weeks from now”. Not using ENDS means that the event continues executing indefinitely.
>
> ENDS supports the same syntax for complex time units as STARTS does.
>
> **You may use STARTS, ENDS, both, or neither in an EVERY clause.**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Your only alternative (and workaround) is to recreate the event (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39173).

Comment: Yes It's optional for CREATE,I have read the documentation. but how do I alter it to NULL? not including it will result in the ENDS to be the same as before the alter

Comment: It cannot be null, it must be a timestamp

Comment: It doesn't make sense you can alter an optional parameter to one of his options. The fact that the documentation doesn't say so is I believe an error in the documentation.

Comment: No but I know it will work. I cant really use that as I have a GUI to alter and create events, and the all code is already based on alter, as it would work for any other change I might need, besides this case.

Comment: The alter only modifies what you tell it to modify, within reason. ENDS must be a timestamp and cannot be Null. Your alternative is to drop the event and recreate it.

Comment: See this bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39173 There is no current workaround

Comment: @eric.itzhak I've modified the answer to repeat the above